# How to set global number format in Oracle Apex 3.2.1

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm having trouble with the number formatting in Apex 3.2.1. NLS_TERRITORY is set to GERMANY, NLS_LANGUAGE to GERMAN. However, the default number formatting is wrong and I would like to fix/change it. I'm wondering why there is an application date format setting but no application number format setting. That would have been really helpful right now. So my question is: how can I set a new number format which will be applied everywhere in my application? Is it possible? If not, what would be the least painful way to to apply the new format mask. I'm mainly concerned with interactive reports. Additionally, if it were possible to change the default format mask for the territory in some configuration file, that would also be an option. Thanks for your input in advance.

Edit:

My problem with the default format is that numbers like 0.34 are being displayed as ",34", but the correct output would be "0,34".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, purely the display then. I don't think there is an easy way to do this for all your fields, but specifying a format mask on those fields, by using for example `FM999G999G990D000`.

That would be annoying for a lot of fields across the application though, i agree. It is even more annoying when only by specifying a format mask, items are recognised as being number fields. Maybe making a plugin, which is identical to a number field, but with a default format mask may do the trick. 
Or query the apex views to find items, then update them (though you will need access to the 'internal' tables of apex, the wwv_* things).

```
select application_name, page_id, page_name, item_name, display_as, display_as_code, format_mask from apex_application_page_items where page_id = 6
```

Which you could then transform into an update...

I've nothing else to offer, so far i've always specified the format mask during development...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that's not my problem. NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS is set correctly. I edited my question to elaborate on my problem further.

Comment: I've edited my answer now you've clarified - although it's probably a far cry from what you're after.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I guess I'll go through all pages and enter the format manually then. Seems to be the quickest way right now.